# The way he did it was different from the way we were used to ？

Tags: sentence-construction

> The way he did it was different from **the way** we were used to.

In the sentence, "we were used to" is a relative clause to identify "the way".
Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. **We were used to** is a relative clause that modifies **the way**. There are two types of relative clause - restrictive and non-restrictive. I guess it's the example of restrictive relative clause.

Please correct me if I am wrong on my statement that it's an example of restrictive relative clause.

Comment: It is indeed *restrictive/defining*.